# Completely remove all OSs from laptop

Tags: windows-10, boot, grub

I have a Dell Inspiron on which i made a partition and installed Ubuntu, then i deleted the Ubuntu partition on Windows 10.

At this point i could restart the |PC and it would boot into Windows, then while trying to fix some things i enabled Safe Mode on the Windows Boot options and when i restarted the computer, it opened GRUB.

Now i cant go into windows nor Ubuntu (As i deleted Ubuntu's partition)

I have tried the bootrec instructions to no avail, at this point i would like to just delete every OS (Windows) and GRUB and install Windows to start fresh.

Any recommendations?

Comment: If you have (external) restore/install media (for Windows), then boot the PC from a Linux LiveCD, and use the `dd if=/dev/null of=/dev/sdX count=63` command to wipe the first "track" of that drive.

Comment: If you want to wipe the drive use Boot 'n' Nuke. But, you can just boot with a Windows 10 installation disc or USB drive and delete all partitions during setup.

Comment: You can always consider buying a new HDD/SDD and swapping it in.

Comment: Juan Goncalves, your only problem is the bootloader... so you want to completely wipe out your Windows *and* Ubuntu? That's overkill, you could try a hammer if you really want to mess things up for no good reason, but **the real answer is just fix the bootloader.** @sawdust I wonder if the default `bs` is always 512, and is the first 32256 bytes all that's required to "mess up" the MBR/GPT and 1st partition in all cases? I'd rather use `gparted` and format each partition to "cleared", I think that's similar to running `wipefs` and changing the partition type, and gui's a plus

Comment: @Xen2050 -- Blocksize of 512 byres should work since it is the PC standard for HDDs (and devices that emulate HDDs, e.g. flash drives, SDcards).  An Advanced Format drive should accept it in emulation mode.  Zeroing out the first sector of the drive should suffice, but I also like to get rid of any bootloader stuff on the first "track".  A zeroed-out MBR sector IMO is better than a new MBR because it forces Windows to initialize the device to Windows' default config (e.g. SDcard has a single logical drive w/o a partition table).

Comment: Thanks guys! I ended up reinstalling ubuntu and wiping everything on the disk so now i only have Ubuntu, in the future ill try to get Windows again, but for now Ubuntu is working and i managed to fix the boot